# Unable to access library of share point in .net core

Tags: sharepoint, .net-core

I got stuck on uploading file on Sharepoint. I am using Microsoft.SharePointOnline2016.CSOM v16.0.

```
public static void UploadDocumentContent(ClientContext ctx, string libraryName)
{
     List oList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
     ctx.Load(oList.RootFolder);
     ctx.Load(oList.Fields);
     try
     {
          ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
}
```

I get error following error.

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Can you specify where you are connecting ?
O365 or OnPremise ? and the code for creating the client context ?

Comment: I am setting my credentials and link in clientContext and then passing to this method. I also verified credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Native SharePoint CSOM is not supported with .NET Core.

UserVoice - [Support .NET Core with CSOM](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16585795-support-net-core-with-csom)

According to above link, Microsoft is thinking about providing support for .NET Core. So, will be supported sometime in the future (no ETA provided).

Having said that, you can take a look at `PnP CSOM` which is a wrapper over Native CSOM. It works with .NET standard.

Nuget - [SharePointPnPCoreOnline - SharePoint PnP Core library for SharePoint Online](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/)